# Play video HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

Is there a ready to use code or some sort to enable the fullscreen button on Safari for the ?video? Currently when the video is loaded, and click on it doesnt work.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" name="media" src="urlvideo">Text</video>
```

What types are supported for the video tag?
Do i need to use type=audio/mp3 for playing mp3   and type=audio/wav etc....?

By they way, the video ui looks different on each browser or not working at all... is there a way to have them all the same look and feel and have them all work on all browsers?

Comment: [Dive Into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html) has a good tutorial on all the nuances of this.

Answer (score 0):

purely css, you can target it with video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button{}, and you'll want to reference this http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/mediaControls.css

Answer (score 0):

To play video when user clicks on it:

```
    document.querySelctor('video').addEvenetListenr('click', function(){
         this.play()
    }, false);
```

To have fullscreen use Webkit and [Gecko full screen API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI)

Answer (score 0):

First, not all browsers have the same video codecs, so not all browsers can play the same videos. I would suggest looking here to choose a format that is supported by the browsers you are targeting:
[HTML5 Video Codec Support By Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)

For Safari specifically, I have gotten this JavaScript to work to get a video to play fullscreen:

> `var vid = document.getElementById('video');`
>   `vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();`
>   `vid.play();`

Also, check out this thread: [Web App - iPad webkitEnterFullscreen - Programatically going full-screen video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685361/web-app-ipad-webkitenterfullscreen-programatically-going-full-screen-video)

Hope that helps!