# AngularJS: How to open native video player on mobiles

Tags: angularjs, video, mobile, video.js

I am using vjs-video AngularJS plugin for rendering videos in my app. On desktop it shows them in ngDialog (by binding dialog window to ng-click of gallery element)

It's working ok, but on the mobiles I want to show native fullscreen player right after user clicked (tapped) gallery item. I know how to detect mobile and desktop in Angular app, but what to do next? Right now user have to tap on gallery item and then dialog is showing, after that user should make second tap on video.js player in dialog and then video start to play in native player, but I want to open native player right after first click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685361/web-app-ipad-webkitenterfullscreen-programatically-going-full-screen-video

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JavaScript "requestFullscreen" api?

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Here's a link to the [mozilla docs on this api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

And here's a link to [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), a library that's supposed to make this even easier.